# Make blocks sticky on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I have the following set of blocks (divs/spans) on a page:

```
CAPTION 1
CONTENT 1

CAPTION 2
CONTENT 2

....

CAPTION N
CONTENT N
```

I need to make the Captions sticky at the top of the page on scroll.
E.g.

```
CAPTION 1
CAPTION 2

CAPTION 3
CONTENT 3
....
```

So, the CONTENT of the 1st and 2nd blocks got collapsed, but the captions remained visible. Besides, I need to add the onclick event for the sticky captions. Once the sticky caption is clicked, the page should be scrolled up to the correspondent CONTENT.

This should work similar to the bootstrap affix plugin, but the captions should become fixed on scroll only.

How can this be achieved? Are there any plugins with the similar functionality?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scrollPosition = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (scrollPosition !== 0) {
    $("#CAPTION1").addClass("fixed");
  } else {
    $("#CAPTION1").removeClass("fixed");
});
```

.fixed class has fixed position and located where you need

Same thing for other Captions

Comment: This won't work, unfortunately. The captions will stick to their current locations and the content blocks will overlap them. A caption block should become sticky once the related content block is hidden, not just 'onscroll' event. I suspect the algorithm is much more complicated and I wonder if there are any ready to use solutions.